# How do I get my movieclip character to move?

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement, flash-cc

I've been trying for a few hours now and I cant get my little character to move with the keyboard.

I have ran a trace to make see if anything was happening and the position value does change but my character doesn't react to that position change.

I receive no errors. Both my Character and BrickBlock are movieclips and they have been imported for ActionScript.

If any other information is needed please let me know. Thank you! :)

My following code:

```
package  {

import flash.events.Event
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class CharMove extends MovieClip {

    var char1 :Character;
    var block :BrickBlock;

    public function CharMove() 
    {           
        char1 = new Character();
        block = new BrickBlock();

        //this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collide)
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kDown);
    }

    /*function collide(e:Event):void
    {
            if(char.hitTestObject(block))
            {
                char.visible = !char.visible;
            }
    }*/

    function kDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch (event.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.LEFT:
                char1.x -= 5;
                trace(char1.x);
                break;

            case Keyboard.RIGHT:
                char1.x +=5;
                trace(char1.x);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Correct me if any of this is incorrect. Based on the details you have here, I am guessing that you see your character on the screen but it does not move. If this is indeed correct, then looking at your code, I see you are creating a character here, within this class and setting its `x` property. Thus, the character you see on screen is not the character you are manipulating here in this code. You need to get a reference of your actual character to be used here. Or, the better option would be to add the movement code, you are starting here, to your character class.

Comment: Yes you are correct. You may be onto something! I was actually thinking that might be the case. :) I'm going to try it out now and see if it works.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you so much Parcell for bringing that to my attention. I just deleted the character on the stage and added in the one I created.
If I were to reference the character on the stage, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: You could get it by name (good reason to name it). `character = stage.getChildByName('myCharacter');`

Comment: But again, there is no reason (that I can see) why couldn't have your movement code within the **Character** class you have.

Comment: I barely have 2 weeks of experience working with actionscript. I'm still learning how I can manipulate things. I wasn't sure if that could have been an option. Now that you told me about it, I will go ahead and start playing around in the character class.
Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider writing a static **Input** class.

```
package input {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Input {

        private static var keys:Array = new Array(255);

        public static function setup(stage:Stage):void {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, KeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, KeyUp);
        }

        private static function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        }

        private static function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        }

        public static function isKeyDown(k:int):Boolean {
            return keys[k];
        }

        public static const A:uint = 65;
        public static const B:uint = 66;
        public static const C:uint = 67;
        // The rest of the keys...
    }
}
```

To use it first call **setup()** which adds the listeners for *KEY_DOWN* and *KEY_UP* events.
They you can easily query keys and do relevant actions accordingly.

```
Input.setup(stage);

/...

if(Input.isKeyDown(Input.A)) {
    char1.x -= 5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. Though it was very put together, the first comment on my question helped me out. But, I will definitely look to your code for further understanding of actionscript.