# How to add keyboard interaction in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, intellij-idea, keyboard-events

I got 16 different buttons in this application, each button playing different kind of sound. Currently i only able to use mouse click to start playing sound, and click again to stop, but now i wish to add shortcut key to access those track buttons, like pressing "q" for track 1, "w" for track 2. Any hints or tips like what am i suppose to do to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

```
private var _ambientTracks:Array = [ambient1, ambient2, ambient3, ambient4];
private var _effectTracks:Array = [effect1, effect2, effect3, effect4];
private var _melodyTracks:Array = [melody1, melody2, melody3, melody4];
private var _beatTracks:Array = [beat1, beat2, beat3, beat4];

//handle click on track invoke  start / stop functions
private function onTrackClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var track:Sprite = event.currentTarget as Sprite;
    var trackName:String = track.name;
    if (trackName in _playingTracks) {
        stopTrack(track);
        delete _playingTracks[trackName];
    } else {
        startTrack(track);
        _playingTracks[trackName] = trackName;
    }
}

//starts track animation and dispatch event for TrackMixer
private function startTrack(track:Sprite):void {
    Actuate.tween(track, 0.6, {alpha: 0.3}).reflect().repeat();
    dispatchEvent(new ObjectEvent(START_TRACK, track.name, true));

}

//stop track animation and dispatch event for TrackMixer
private function stopTrack(track:Sprite):void {
    Actuate.stop(track, "alpha");
    track.alpha = 1;
    dispatchEvent(new ObjectEvent(STOP_TRACK, track.name, true));
}
```

Comment: Making keyboard interaction is pretty straightforward, what exactly you stuck on?

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26533789/1134902), might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Cherniv Because in this case im handle the click function by tracing the track name like _playingTracks[trackName] = trackName; in the array, but for making keyboard interaction, i have to make 16 different function right?

Comment: @iggy hi, i've seen your answer there, but what if i want to make like pressing "a" to trigger the sound, and pressing "a" again to stop the sound?

Comment: @withinboy In that case you need to keep track of the toggles, which is a simple boolean value e.g: `isSoundOn = true`. You could make an array with 255 entries for `toggles` of each key, and when a key is pressed set it like so: `toggles[e.keyCode] != toggles[e.keyCode];`

Comment: @iggy Thanks for the explanation, but i have a question, for example i want to press "A" to start track 1(ambient1), "B" for track 2, so i need to define the keycode A = 65, but can i define it again like A = 65 = track 1(ambient1)? Because i still not very familiar how keycode work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic concept similar to what you are trying to achieve you need to listen for a key press and use the specific key code handle what key is being pressed, if you have lots of key commands I suggest using a switch case.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(30,30,30);
mc.graphics.endFill();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUp);

function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(e.keyCode == 81){//q
                addChild(mc);
            }
        if(e.keyCode == 87){//w
                if(mc.stage){
                        removeChild(mc);
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the concept, but what if i want to make like press "q" to start the sound and animation, and press "q" again to stop the sound and animation? Can i use back the same concept?

Answer (score 0):

It would still use the similar concepts, however you need to someway to "toggle" the same key to play and stop. A boolean variable would fit nicely to track the state of the key press.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

//Code to create a simple black circle xpos: 30 ypos: 30 radius: 30
var mc: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
mc.graphics.drawCircle(30, 30, 30);
mc.graphics.endFill();

//Adding event listener to stage for a key up event
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);

/*
Creating a boolean value to track "on" or "off" for one key. 
Default value for boolean is false.
*/
var bool: Boolean;


function keyUp(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if (e.keyCode == 81) {
        if (!bool) {
            addChild(mc);
            bool = true;
        } else {
            if (mc.stage) {
                removeChild(mc);
                bool = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

if key == q and bool == false add mc to stage and set bool to true.
The next time this method is called, bool will be true in which case the else statement
will be fired off (because bool is not false). The stage will be checked to see if mc exists to avoid errors, mc will be removed from stage, and bool will be set back to false in order to meet the condition of the if statement (bool is false).

Comment: Thanks, but in this case im using array like:

      if (trackName in _playingTracks) {
        stopTrack(track);
        delete _playingTracks[trackName];
    } else {
        startTrack(track);
        _playingTracks[trackName] = trackName;
    }
}

so what if i want to define like if (e.keyCode == 81), then play track 1(ambient1)? i need to define 1 by 1? or can i use back the same method _playingTracks[trackName] = trackName; and check the keyCode in the same time? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been away on holiday. So if I recall you want to press a button that goes to the next track? If thats the case put in some sort of counter and then when the key is pressed increment the counter and then play the array value by using the counter. e.g. button pressed, counter incremented to one play arrValue[counter], and so on until it reaches the array length and set counter back to 0.